# How to show the closed messages section even though there are no conversations using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

i have 2 tabs

1. I have active messages tab, which is working fine.
2. i have closed messages tab, if i dont have messages in the closed message tab there comes an error, that error is because i have looped in front end.

So, can anyone help me to solve this issue..
Even though i have no conversation in the closed tab, then it must show the empty field and if i change tab also it must work fine.

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let reply of message_close.messages">
          <img [src]="reply.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
          <p><b>{{reply.name}} </b> <span> {{reply.updated_at | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}} - {{reply.updated_at | date:'h:mm'}}</span></p>
          <p>{{reply.text}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Ts:

```
loadMessages() {
    this.service
          .getMessages()
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.messagesdata = data;
              this.activeMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true && msg.from_user_name !== 'Anonymus' && msg.messages.length > 0)
              this.closedMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == false && msg.from_user_name !== 'Anonymus' && msg.messages.length > 0);
              if (this.closedMessages.length > 0) {
                if(!this.message_close) {
                  var test2 = this.message_close = this.closedMessages[0];
                  this.message_idc = this.closedMessages[0].id;
                  this.message_close.messages.map(function(msg) {
                    if(msg.from_user_id == test2.from_user_id) {
                      msg.from_user_image = test2.from_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.from_user_image = test2.to_user_image;
                    }
                    if(msg.to_user_id == test2.to_user_id) {
                      msg.to_user_image = test2.to_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.to_user_image = test2.to_user_image;
                    }
                  })
                }
              }              
            },error => {});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using ngIf,

```
    <ul>
       <li *ngIf="message_close == undefined || message_close.messages.length == 0|| message_close.messages.length == undefined">
          <p>there is no closed messages.</p>
         </li>

        <li *ngFor="let reply of message_close.messages" >
          <img [src]="reply.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
          <p><b>{{reply.name}} </b> <span> {{reply.updated_at | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}} - {{reply.updated_at | date:'h:mm'}}</span></p>
          <p>{{reply.text}}</p>
        </li>

      </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but, i am not getting according to my requirement

Comment: what is your requirement? i show you the way to achieve your goal by using ngIf

Comment: in close message tab, i have empty conversations.. so it must be blank.. and the tabs must also work

Comment: what happened if you try as i said?

Comment: Now, i am getting this error, "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined"

Comment: in this line error <li *ngIf="message_close.messages.length == 0|| message_close.messages.length == undefined">

Comment: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170019/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-hitesh-kansagara).